# How to put four lists on a page, each taking one quarter of the page?

Tags: formatting, lists

I am trying to add a SWOT analysis to my document and would like to have it set out in a 2x2 grid, where each grid space takes up 1/4 of the page regardless of the content.  Is this possible with LaTeX?

Comment: Could you add a MWE or a drawing of what you're trying to accomplish? It's hard to figure it out from just your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many, many ways to achieve this. One possibility is `tcolorbox` using its `raster` library. The basic format is written quite easily.

- Every `\tcbitem` inside the `tcbitemize` environment fills one quarter of the page.
- The `raster height` can be set to a smaller value than `\textheight`, if not the whole page should be filled.

Without too much decorations, this gives:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster height=\textheight,enhanced,sharp corners,
  colback=yellow!10,colframe=yellow!50!black]
\tcbitem
  \lipsum[2]
\tcbitem
  \lipsum[3]
\tcbitem
  \lipsum[4]
\tcbitem
  \lipsum[5]
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a next step, the four boxes can be decorated. I try to mimic some classic SWOT pictures with the next example. The optional parameter of `\tcbitem` can take any formating option of a `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum,lmodern}

\tcbset{letter/.style={overlay={\node[text=white,opacity=50] at (interior) {\fontsize{7cm}{7cm}\sffamily\bfseries #1};}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster height=\textheight,
  raster equal skip=0pt,
  enhanced,sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,frame hidden]
\tcbitem[letter=S,colback=red!30]
  \lipsum[2]
\tcbitem[letter=W,colback=yellow!30]
  \lipsum[3]
\tcbitem[letter=O,colback=blue!30]
  \lipsum[4]
\tcbitem[letter=T,colback=green!30]
  \lipsum[5]
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remark: Be sure to update [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) to its latest version since I used some quite new features.

Comment: Nice and +1. Always adding new features and I miss them some times. Good work. I hope very soon `tcolorbox` too, will become a swiss army knife. :)

Comment: You sir, are awesome :)